# Filter tests and generate coverage in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco

I'm trying to generate a coverage report from the command line (for Jenkins automation) for a subset of my tests and it's providing irksome.

I can run a subset of tests with:

./gradlew clean product:testMockDebug --tests testfilter1* --tests testfilter2* --testfilter3* jacoco

But it will report:

> :jacocoTestReport SKIPPED

every time;

And I can't run

./gradlew clean test --tests testfilter1* --tests testfilter2* --testfilter3* jacoco

As "test" doesn't support --tests:

> Unknown command-line option '--tests'.

I have tried adding a filter into my build.gradle file; but I can't work out where to do it to get it to work; inside "allprojects"?

How can I generate a coverage report from the command line for a set of filtered tests?

Android Studio 
Gradle: 3.4.1
Groovy: 2.4.7

Comment: What kind is your `test` task? The standard `test` task of type `Test` **does** support multiple `--tests` options.

Comment: I don't have "test" defined as a task in my build.gradle; this is also for Android Studio, should have said.

Comment: Still, what type is the `test` task? Add `println test.getClass()` to your buildscript.

Comment: AH right; can't check that now (away from project) but they are unit tests, not instrumentation tests.

Comment: To see the reason of "SKIPPED" you can increase logging level of Gradle using `--info`.

Comment: "class org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test_Decorated"

Comment: Aha; "--info" gives me Skipping task ':jacocoTestReport' as task onlyIf is false. Helpful; thanks :)

Comment: So it is the normal `Test` type, that type can handle `--tests` parameters, even in very old versions. I really cannot see why it shouldn't work to use them.

Comment: Yes it is helpful - `onlyIf` for `jacocoTestReport` is defined as https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/2866c30a78bf97dd30e1f100c21de8c46cdf04c7/subprojects/jacoco/src/main/java/org/gradle/testing/jacoco/tasks/JacocoReportBase.java#L58-L68 , i.e. that only if there are execution data files. Also please consider providing [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem to avoid guessing and losing time by others.